# Assign a record as a look up object before insertion

Tags: apex, lookup, apexrest, insert

I am attempting to write an api endpoint meant to upload many objects of one type. This object, `MyObject`, contains a lookup field that looks up another MyObject record for translation reasons.

Imagine that I am going to get all of MyObjects in one body, both the original and the translated versions. I know that a look up field is based on `Id` so I was wondering if I am  going to need to create all of the records, insert them in the database, and then after that assign the relationships?

In other words:

```
// OPTION 1
List<MyObject__c> newObjects = new MyObject__c();
for (bodyObject reqObj : reqBodyObjects) {
    MyObject__c obj = new MyObject__c();
    // set the fields
    obj.translationId = reqObj.translationId;
    newObjects.add(obj);
}
insert newObjects;

for (MyObject__c objA : newObjects) {
    for (MyObject__c objB : newObjects) {
        if (objA.transaltionId == objB.translationId) {
            objA.MyObject__c = objB.Id;
            objB.MyObject__c = objA.Id;
        }
    }
}


// OPTION 2
Map<Decimal, MyObject_c> objList = new Map<Decimal, MyObject__c>()
List<MyObject__c> newObjects = new MyObject__c();
for (bodyObject reqObj : reqBodyObjects) {
    MyObject__c obj = new MyObject__c();
    // set the fields
    obj.translationId__c = reqObj.translationId;
    newObjects.add(obj);

    if (objList.containsKey(obj.translationId__c)) {
        MyObject__c translatedObj = objList.get(obj.translationId__c);
        obj.MyObject__c = translatedObj.Id;
        translatedObj.MyObject__c = obj.Id;
    } else {
        objList.put(obj.translationId__c, obj);
    }

}
insert newObjects;
```

Is option 2 possible? I don't believe it is because `Id` doesn't get set until insert, but I wanted to make sure. Or what would be a suggested method of doing this relationship, for example, can you base Look Up objects on a unique field other than Id?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to insert parent and child records with the statement when the records have the same `SObjectType`. You will need to insert any parents, then insert or update any children to populate the lookups.

See also the below passage from the `Apex Developer Guide` (emphasis mine):

> #### [Creating Parent and Child Records in a Single Statement Using Foreign Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm)
>
> You can use external ID fields as foreign keys to create parent and child records ***of different sObject types*** in a single step instead of creating the parent record first, querying its ID, and then creating the child record.
>
> ...
>
> You can create related records that are up to 10 levels deep. Also, ***the related records created in a single call must have different sObject types.*** For more information, see [Creating Records for Different Object Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm#MixedSaveSection) in the SOAP API Developer Guide.